# Why do I not get any output for this code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-acne-remedies#acv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
soup1 = str(soup.prettify)
for i in soup1:
    a=soup1.index(i)
    if soup1[a:a+7]=="header":
            print(soup1[a+9:a+30])
    else:
            pass
```

soup1 contains 50 headers but still I don't get any output

Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Can update your question with a small sample of what is in `soup1`?

Comment: That's like 4000+ lines but I got the solutions, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change :** `soup1[a:a+7]=="header"` **to** `soup1[a:a+6] == header":` **and** **print to** `print(soup1[a+9:a+30])`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-acne-remedies#acv'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup1 = str(soup.prettify)
for a in range(len(soup1)):
    if soup1[a:a+6] == "header":
            print(soup1[a+9:a+30])
    else:
            pass
```

Please find the working code attached [here](https://trinket.io/python3/a5bd54189b).

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something a bit weird. `index` finds the first instance of a character in a string, so you're looking up for each character the first time it appears, then grabbing the next 7 characters. If there's a single instance of h before header (I can think of one!) the whole thing will fail.

You also probably want i+6, as header is 6 characters - the below code works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-acne-remedies#acv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
soup1 = str(soup.prettify)
for i in range(len(soup1)):
    if soup1[i:i+6] == "header":
            print(soup1[i+9:i+30])
    else:
            pass
```

Juan Pethes points out I should also show you how to parse this in a nicer way. The info you want is json encoded script data. Here's how you can get it out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

req = requests.get('https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-acne-remedies#acv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

code = str([i for i in soup.find_all("script") if 'module={}' in str(i)][0].string)
health_dta = json.loads(code[code.index("__NEXT_DATA__")+len("__NEXT_DATA__")+1:])
dta={tab['header'][0]:tab for tab in health_dta['props']['data']['tabs'] if 'header' in tab and tab['header']}
print(dta)
```

Yields:

```
{'What is acne?': {'id': 'what-it-is', 'title': 'What it is', 'isCollapsable': False, 'header': ['What is acne?'], 'body': [{'tagName': 'p', 'source': 'Acne is a skin condition that occurs when your skin follicles become ...
```

Comment: This seems to work, although a better way may be finding the header tags actually using the `bs4` module, instead of doing it manually with a string.

Comment: @juanpethes added the more maintainable solution. Though, sadly, I have seen string parsing of this kind of thing in actual use.